# Uv lines are only visible in edit mode

Tags: uv

[image]

It's easy to paint with a guide line like that on the tutorial, but I can't.[image]

I only get a guide line when I'm in edit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching the viewport shading mode to Material Preview (Top right corner of 3D view window).
Also try Texture Paint mode (Top left corner of 3D viewport window or Ctrl+Tab in the 3D viewport).
[image]

Comment: I can see the lines in uv paint mode but not in uv edit mode.

Comment: Don't use edit or object mode, only use Texture Paint mode for texture painting

Comment: I mean Uv editing tab. not edit mode.

Comment: It looks like your trying to texture paint, if so use the Texure Paint tab and Texture Paint mode, do not use the UV Editor tab, Edit mode or Object mode.
The UV editor is for mapping the images to your object, then you switch to paint mode to paint onto that image

Comment: oh.. ok thank you so much^^*

Comment: Always a pleasure, never a chore.